# How to depend on a hash, i.e. always execute hash calculation, but only rebuild if it changed?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want an expensive recipe only to run when there was a file added or removed. To generate a hash, I used `find dir -name '*.cpp' | git hash-object --stdin` essentially, as the content of the files don't matter at that step.

I tried:

```
# forcing to always calculate the hash
.PHONY: calc_hash
calc_hash:
    do_find_and_update_fileshash_only_if_different.sh

# depend on the calc_hash without automatically be out-of-date
files.hash: | calc_hash

someothertarget: files.hash
   <some recipe>
```

The script only writes when old hash != new hash. Still, after a change, `someothertarget` at first does not get rebuilt, then, on second invocation, does get rebuilt. It looks like the change of `files.hash` done by the script is not yet considered in the same run.

It's on Windows using mingw32-make if that matters. Not using a script would be fine, but didn't get it to work either. [Compare this](https://medium.com/@mtiller/using-git-hashes-in-makefile-rules-387a099b9cb), but it uses variables always evaluated and I didn't like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what happens when a phony target is also an order-only prerequisite of another target, but it's a bit unusual. If your `do...` script modifies `files.hash` only if something changed, you could try the following:

```
someothertarget: files.hash
    <some recipe>

files.hash: FORCE
    do_find_and_update_fileshash_only_if_different.sh

.PHONY: FORCE
```

As `files.hash` is not phony `someothertarget` will not be systematically rebuilt, make will consider its last modification time. But as `FORCE` is phony make will always try to rebuild `files.hash`.

The trick is to avoid a direct dependency of the costly target on a phony one because it would be systematically rebuilt. Instead we can use an indirect dependency. And of course, the intermediate target must be modified by its recipe only when we need to rebuild the costly target.

All this can easily be tested with, for instance:

```
$ cat Makefile
CHANGE := NO

costly: changed
    @echo "building $@"
    @touch $@

changed: FORCE
    @echo "do we need to build $@?"
    @if ! [ -f "$@" ] || [ "$(CHANGE)" = "yes" ]; then \
        echo "  yes, building $@"; \
        touch "$@"; \
    else \
        echo "  no, not building $@"; \
    fi

.PHONY: FORCE

$ rm -f changed costly
$ make
do we need to build changed?
  yes, building changed
building costly
$ make
do we need to build changed?
  no, not building changed
$ make CHANGE=yes
do we need to build changed?
  yes, building changed
building costly
```

Comment: Using the variable `CHANGE` isn't really the same, is it? It should be automatic. Or was it just for demonstration purposes?

Comment: But that seemed to work, thanks! So the trick is that the FORCE target is always remade, the files.hash's recipe also always runs, but then, when it comes to the someothertarget, that's forgotten and only the timestamp is compared! And with order-only, I could get rid of the phony's "always-out-of-date", but somehow the timestamp wasn't considered.

Comment: You got everything right. And yes, the `CHANGE` variable is just for demo. It's a way to emulate the real thing.